# How to configure paths for the layout to be rendered by ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-framework, express

Following is the code in config/routes.js file

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.render('login/login.jade', {
            layout : 'layouts/login.jade',
            title : 'Express'
        });
    });
};
```

Basically what I am trying is to render views/login/login.jade within views/layouts/login.jade.

But the path that express.js looks for to find the layout file is relative to views/login
Following is the error I get.

```
**failed to locate view "layouts/login.jade", tried:
  - ../msf_showcase_exp/views/login/layouts/login.jade
  - ../msf_showcase_exp/views/login/../msf_showcase_exp/views/layouts/login.jade**
```

Is the anyway to specify in Express.js to search for the layout in views/layout. ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this should work. just tried it (with node 0.4.11, express 2.4.6 and jade 0.15.4)

folders look like this

```
jadetest
|
-- app.js
|
-- package.json
|
-- public
|
-- route
|  |
|  -- router.js
|
-- views
   |
   -- index
   |  |
   |  -- index.jade
   |
   -- layouts
      |
      -- layout.jade
```

in app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = module.exports = express.createServer();
var router = require('./route/router')(app);
```

in router.js

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index/index', {
        title: 'Express',
        layout: 'layouts/layout'
      });
  });
};
```